# canonical NSE differentiation between names and expressions

Tags: r, expression, non-standard-evaluation

Is there a canonical base-R method to determine if a function argument is an object name vice a literal/expression?

While NSE is typically discouraged, occasionally somebody has a good idea and wants to use it. The simplest use-case that I might justify as "convenient" is `data.frame`: if you include saved vectors, it will use the object name as the column name. (In fact, many classes seem to teach this as the best/only way to make frames.)

```r
vec <- 1234:1235
data.frame(vec)
#    vec
# 1 1234
# 2 1235
```

But feed the raw vector, and it does not go as well:

```r
data.frame(1234:1235)
#   X1234.1235
# 1       1234
# 2       1235
```

A common way in base R to do this form of NSE is to use `deparse(substitute(x))`, which will return a string of either the object name (`"vec"`) or the expression passed as a literal (`"1234:1235"`).

Some `is.*` functions exist (e.g., `is.object`, `is.expression`), though they are for different purposes. I wouldn't want to rely on `is.vector` or similar structure-specific functions, as that doesn't generalize into more-complicated structured parameters (without significant customization).

My thought was to `try(get(.))` the object, and if that fails for whatever reason (typically "not found"), then the argument is most likely an expression or literal. (This does not work if the NSE object is not found: `library(ggplot2)`, and there is not likely to be an object named `"ggplot2"` in the calling environment.)

For example,

```r
func <- function(x, ...) {
  xname <- deparse(substitute(x))
  isobj <- !inherits(try(get(xname), silent = TRUE), "try-error")
  if (isobj) "yes" else "no"
}

func(zz)
# [1] "yes"
func(c(zz))
# [1] "no"
```

(Assume that `func` is meant to do more with `isobj` than just return a string.)

Extending that method with a technique for dealing with the ellipsis, I can do:

```r
my_names <- function(...) {
  dot_obj_expr <- sapply(eval(substitute(alist(...))), deparse)
  nms <- names(dot_obj_expr)
  if (is.null(nms)) nms <- rep("", length(dot_obj_expr))
  hasgoodnames <- nzchar(nms) |
    !sapply(dot_obj_expr, function(obj) inherits(try(get(obj), silent = TRUE), "try-error"))
  # rational starting point
  goodnames <- sprintf("V%i", seq_along(dot_obj_expr))
  # replace those that were already named
  goodnames[nzchar(nms)] <- nms[nzchar(nms)]
  # replace those that were not named but appear to be an object-name
  goodnames[!nzchar(nms) & hasgoodnames] <- dot_obj_expr[!nzchar(nms) & hasgoodnames]
  goodnames
}

zz <- 1
my_names(zz, abc = 1:3, 1:3)
# [1] "zz"  "abc" "V3" 

### less clear when an arg is not found
rm(zz)
my_names(zz, abc = 1:3, 1:3)
# [1] "V1"  "abc" "V3"
```

which provides a (perhaps) more-reasonable convention for using the names.

I haven't done benchmarking or profiling to know if this would have any significant "penalty". I believe that `try(get(.))` is fairly efficient, and since the code so far does not alter any of the objects, I see no memory-copy being needed.

(This question is informed by advanced-R, http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's helpful, but it seems that you just want to check of the parameter is a symbol vs something else. You can do that with

```
func <- function(x, ...) {
  xobj <- substitute(x)
  if (is.symbol(xobj)) "yes" else "no"
}
func(zz)
# [1] "yes"
func(c(zz))
# [1] "no"
```

This will return "yes" for `zz` whether or not the variable `zz` actually exists which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Clearly that is what I was missing ... looking after `substitute` but before `deparse` or `eval`.

Comment: This has the added benefit (and liability) of not determining if the object exists, so `func(no_such_object)` still returns `"yes"`. This is looking for symbols, not names of existing objects. That's a good distinction.